# Cypress detected a promise when no promises were created

Tags: cypress

I have this Cypress command where I'm doing checks for elements within `.row`. It works fine if I'm looping through `.row` elements but it fails if I'm passing in a specific `.row` element. I'm not sure what to make of the error message because I'm not using promises anywhere.

**Command:**

```
Cypress.Commands.add('normalRowCheck', row => {
    cy.wrap(row).find('button').should('have.text', 'X')
    cy.wrap(row).find('form').should('not.exist')
    cy.wrap(row).find('input').should('not.exist')
    cy.wrap(row).should('have.class', 'row')
})
```

**Works:**

```
cy.get('.row').each((row, i) => { 
    cy.wrap(row).find('div').should('have.text', 'Adding Task ' + (i+4))
    cy.normalRowCheck(row)
})
```

**Doesn't Work:**

```
cy.normalRowCheck(cy.get('.row').last())
```

**Error: Shows up on first call of `cy.wrap`**

Cypress detected that you returned a promise from a command while also invoking one or more cy commands in that promise.

The command that returned the promise was:

> cy.wrap()

The cy command you invoked inside the promise was:

> cy.then()

Because Cypress commands are already promise-like, you don't need to wrap them or return your own promise.

Cypress will resolve your command with whatever the final Cypress command yields.

The reason this is an error instead of a warning is because Cypress internally queues commands serially whereas Promises execute as soon as they are invoked. Attempting to reconcile this would prevent Cypress from ever resolving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I think there's an error in declaring `row` => should be `cy.get('row').last()`.
2. I don't believe that Cypress has finished yielded the element for `row` before you try to wrap it in your second example. You could fix this in a number of ways, but here are two examples.

First, you could simply pass the yielded element to the [`.then()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/then), which then has a [JQuery element](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/get#Yields) that your custom command can correctly wrap.

```js
// using a `.then()`
cy.get('.row').last().then(($row) => {
  cy.normalRowCheck($row);
})
```

You can modify your custom command to automatically be a [child command that requires an element,](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands#Require-Element) and not have to actually pass the row yourself.

```js
// modifying your custom commands to receive the previously yielded subject
Cypress.Commands.add('normalRowCheck', {prevSubject: 'element'}, (row) => {
    cy.wrap(row).find('button').should('have.text', 'X')
    cy.wrap(row).find('form').should('not.exist')
    cy.wrap(row).find('input').should('not.exist')
    cy.wrap(row).should('have.class', 'row')
});

// using the command
cy.get('.row').last().normalRowCheck();
// using the command with .each()
cy.get('.row').each((row, i) => { 
    cy.wrap(row).find('div').should('have.text', 'Adding Task ' + (i+4))
  cy.wrap(row).normalRowCheck();
});
```

As another point of advice, mixing variables and Cypress commands generally doesn't work out without heavily testing that your code will execute and not have any race conditions. When possible, try chaining your commands, or removing the need for declaring something as a variable.